# Is $L:=\{w \in \Sigma^* | \#_a{(w)} \leq \#_b{(w)} \leq 2\#_a{(w)} \}$ context-free?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Given an alphabet $\Sigma:=\{a,b\}$, denote $\#_\sigma{(w)}$ the number of occurrences of a character $\sigma \in \Sigma$ in a word $w \in \Sigma^*$.

Define $L:=\{w \in \Sigma^* | \#_a{(w)} \leq \#_b{(w)} \leq 2\#_a{(w)} \}$. Is $L$ context-free?

I've tried constructing an appropriate PDA, but I'm not sure how to enforce both $\#_a{(w)} \leq \#_b{(w)}$ and $\#_b{(w)} \leq 2\#_a{(w)}$ simultaneously. Any clues?

Comment: Use the pumping lemma to increase the number of b's.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Every change in the number of b's using the pumping lemma would possibly change the number of a's, since there are no constraints forcing b's to be consecutive.

Comment: I think this problem may be easier to solve by thinking about Context Free Grammars rather than PDAs. Can you please clarify if this is a homework question?

Comment: It's a question I found in old lecture notes. A CFG solution would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put this in spoiler blocks so it can be used as a sequence of hints.

> Basically, the trick is to embrace non-determinism.

CFGs 1:

> Have rules that produce one b and one a, and *also* rules that produce one b with two a's. Don't forget to leave *complete* freedom of ordering for the a's and b's.

CFGs 2:

> So two of your rules could be T -> TaTbT and T -> TbTaTaT, though there are probably nicer solutions.

PDAs 1:

> Consider the stack to be a single integer counter representing how many a's you still have to account for, so reading an 'a' can push a symbol representing "+1".

PDAs 2:

> Once b's start popping those, you'll also need a way to handle negative counts...

PDAs 3:

> ...so reading an 'a' can ALSO pop a "-1" symbol instead.

PDAs 4:

> Every b accounts for either 1 or 2 a's, so let it push one OR two "-1"s (or pop "+1"s).

PDAs 5:

> Set it up so you can check for an empty stack at the end.